# My highest-voted answers to closed questions are being deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, 10k-tools, moderators

Recently (as in today) the mods seems to be deleting every closed answer I have answered:

[image: mods on a roll]

The problem is, my rep is taking a serious hit. I was >2600, now I'm down to 2550, and at the rate it's going, it won't be long and I will drop below 2500 - and I was really hoping to close some stuff.

Could some 10k users check this out, make sure that it's not some riled up 20k/mod user after me? For your reference, the links are [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CE0QFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257678/how-do-people-get-started-in-ios-development&ei=Mp2NUYWRKeahiQLAvYCgDA&usg=AFQjCNHHe_KP5v_q6mscCOMRB0ywgxG0jg&sig2=Qi7eExBU_o6H8gIoGF5gSg&bvm=bv.46340616,d.cGE), [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256911/disable-my-ios-app-from-being-downloaded-by-general-public&ei=dZ2NUaGOGo6GiQLTkYGIBQ&usg=AFQjCNF-ITDKlPsIYS4Xg-w3fpsvdptPrw&sig2=063Hysp4ERzIeeLTfYzTOw&bvm=bv.46340616,d.cGE) and [here (one of my top voted answers, not shown in screenshot).](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F13024485%2Frejected-from-apple-store-what-do-i-do&ei=vp2NUb0DqLSJAriSgPAI&usg=AFQjCNEB8Lxq0ieiRjcycN8qVuCt4JjvwA&sig2=cgbOluXuEIDmd48USCoWCQ)

Comment: Stop answering off-topic, subjective questions? - PS *none* of those questions were deleted by moderators.

Comment: If you are that concerned about your rep, I'd suggest you focus on answering questions that aren't close worthy. Also, 48 points isn't a "serious hit".

Comment: Note that it requires at least 3 20k users to delete a question. Some of the delete voters were shared between the questions, but it is more likely they were responding to the same flags.

Comment: OK, it seems it's not that. Is the same person flagging my answered questions over and over?

Comment: it won't be long and I will drop below 2500 - and I was really hoping to close some stuff. -- there's kind of irony in this.

Comment: @djechlin Yes, I know. I was wondering how long it would take for someone to notice :)

Comment: 20k users don't have any way of telling who flagged the posts (moderators would, though). On the other hand, are you really surprised your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257678/how-do-people-get-started-in-ios-development), which is a long explanation of how to use Google, got deleted?

Comment: FWIW, none of these deletions were directly in response to flags. Some community members do revisit older, closed questions and vote to delete them just as a way of cleaning up (there are tools available to 10K users that can assist in this).

Comment: ^^ exactly, its nothing personal. No mod is out to get you, on my review its the opposite. Its simply a case of bad questions.

Comment: ask them to put your questions on the list : http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73455/155223

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should *assume* that closed questions will eventually be deleted. This is not always true, but it's a common outcome.

If you've answered a question which may be considered inappropriate, you should consider two actions to prevent the closing and deletion of the question (and your answer with it):

1. Edit the question to make it clearly on-topic and constructive (also fix any glaring grammar or formatting issues, since those never help).
2. If the question is not a programming question but would be on-topic for a different Stack Exchange site then flag it and suggest migration (for instance, App Store questions *may* be better-received on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/are-questions-about-app-stores-on-topic-here)).

Comment: Thanks. Have there been a bunch of deletions today?

Comment: There are a bunch of deletions *every* day.

Answer (score 16):

This isn't a problem.  50 rep is not a serious hit and you're kind of doing [this](http://xkcd.com/605/):

[image: So many husbands]

Anyway, I'm going to give you the rather officious advice that "someone is out to get me" appear very far down your list of troubleshooting strategies.  It's reminiscent of blaming the compiler in your first few weeks of C.  This should have all come to your mind before trying to figure out if there is a miscreant in the community:

- Do you understand why questions are deleted?
- Do you understand why the questions were of low quality?
- Do you understand *how* questions are deleted?

If these all pass, next up:

- Have you found an explanation for the judgment calls, even if they strike you as erratic?
- Have you reached out to the community (e.g. posting on meta) trying to figure out what happened?

If you have a meta post where everyone is confused as to why your questions are deleted, *that* is when it's appropriate to ask someone to "look into it" and make sure there's no weird system bugs or anyone out to get you.  Right now, it's like we're writers of a C compiler, and you just asked us what's wrong with our compiler when your program to calculate interest payments failed.

Regarding the policy itself, if you want this policy changed you're going to have to make a *serious* case for why our deletion policy needs to change.  Or why users should retain rep for deleted questions and answers - when we delete a question we're kind of saying it doesn't really attest to, well, a user's reputation.

Anyway as it stands your question is just a personal gripe.  It won't get any sympathy unless you think and articulate that there is a problem with our policy that is hurting the site.  As far as I can tell, you just got a somewhat sore push to focus your efforts on higher quality questions, which means poor quality questions will get fewer answers and higher quality questions will get more answers...  which is exactly what we want.

Answer (score 8):

Join the club.

[image: Deleted answers]

Damn moderators.

Comment: Where is this list?

Comment: @Undo Those are my own most highly voted answers. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard?tab=answers

Comment: @Undo Nah, easy come easy go. You can tell from the titles that none of those questions were really that good. The standards that we have now hadn't been established back in 2008-09.

Comment: I want to see this question reopened: **What language has the longest "Hello world" program?** --- How is this subjective and not within the rules of the site? (obviously assuming we do not get into doing the programming trickery)...

Comment: @aditya Probably not on topic because there's no specific problem to solve, and we all hate fun. Might be interesting for Code Golf though.

Comment: @slhck: There is no specific problem to solve simply doesn't mean they would become off-topic/not-constructive - take for example the questions like "what is xyz?" (-- [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)). Moreover, it might be fun but the question seems useful to me.